# Call new Date with union type "number | string"

Tags: typescript

Consider the following snippet (see also [TS Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20nr%3A%20number%20%3D%20123456%3B%0D%0Avar%20str%3A%20string%20%3D%20%222015-01-01T12%3A00%3A00%22%3B%0D%0Avar%20both%3A%20number%20%7C%20string%20%3D%20123456%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20myDate%3A%20Date%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AmyDate%20%3D%20new%20Date%28nr%29%3B%0D%0AmyDate%20%3D%20new%20Date%28str%29%3B%0D%0AmyDate%20%3D%20new%20Date%28both%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20Compile%20error)):

```
var nr: number = 123456;
var str: string = "2015-01-01T12:00:00";
var both: number | string = 123456;

var myDate: Date;

myDate = new Date(nr);
myDate = new Date(str);
myDate = new Date(both); // <-- Compile error
```

That final line gives a compiler error:

> Argument of type `number | string` is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

However, since there's a `Date(...)` constructor for both types I'd assume the above would work.

I can workaround the issue because there is another constructor taking `any` parameter:

```
myDate = new Date(<any> both);
```

But what if that constructor wasn't there, e.g. if this scenario occurred in my own class?

Is there any way to get this to work properly? Or is the union type a design smell here indicating my definitions need to be changed?

I've checked the [TS Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook) but it has no section on union types. I've tried solving it myself but didn't get past the `<any>` trick mentioned above. I've gone through the suggested duplicates and similar questions on SO but did not find an answer so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could extend Date's constructor interface to support this; probably not the nicest solution but it seems to work...

```
interface DateConstructor {
    new (value: number | string): Date;
}

var nr: number = 123456;
var str: string = "2015-01-01T12:00:00";
var both: string | number = "123456";

var myDate: Date;

myDate = new Date(nr);
myDate = new Date(str);
myDate = new Date(both); // <-- No more compile error
```

I think union types are treated as first class citizens in TypeScript, that is, for example: `string | number` is it's own type, to which a `string` or `number` can be assigned. In this respect, `value: string` and `value: number` do not match the type signature `value: string | number` - therefore it sort of makes sense to extend the `DateConstructor` to support this.

Answer (score 3):

This has been discussed over on the Typescript github project.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1805

To summarise, it would be nice to have this work in simple situations like the one you've presented, but in more complex situations it falls apart.

> Essentially the overload set was used to create information tying the type of argument 1 to the type of argument 2 (and can be used likewise to tie this to a return type). With a union type that information is lost and any combination of argument types becomes allowed.

Their suggestion is to have coding standards in place that say function types should use union types rather than overloads.

> See #6735 - we discussed and our plan is to mitigate this by providing a TS Lint rule and guidance that you should never write a series of overloads which have an equivalent representation in union types.
>
> Somehow making this work as part of signature overload resolution is just way too complicated.

Comment: This is excellent info, thank you. I've accepted the other answer as it's the solution(/workaround) I ended up using, but +1 here as well!

Comment: @Jeroen That makes sense to me! While I think I've provided useful/interesting information, series0ne directly answered the question with a way of doing this. Thanks for the upvote :)